# Java Sockets and threads

Tags: java, sockets, server

Hello I am doing this assignment, and i can't really figure this out. Here is how the assignment sounds:

**Stimulate a large football stadium with many turnstiles that each updates a shared counter for each spectator that passes a turnstile.**

**The turnstile should use a Network Connection and TCP to update counter.**

*1.Design a TCP server and a simple protocol where each turnstile initially reports that it is a turnstile (to distinguish from Monitor-clients se next step), its id(turnstile1-turnstile-n) and then reports an increment for each spectator that passes the turnstile.*

**And we are told that we dont have to implement the turstile-clients, we should use telnet to stimulate the turnstiles.**

The problem I have is that I dont know how to use threads, I just started learning about them, The way I understand the assignment is that I should give every turnstile a thread is that wrong? 
I know I have to use threads because, later in the assignment I have to identify race condition problems. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Server { 
  static String ip; 
  static int port; 
  static int count; 

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();

    serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 23));

    while (true) {

        Socket turnstile = serverSocket.accept(); 
        PrintStream printToTerminal = new PrintStream(turnstile.getOutputStream());
        printToTerminal.println("Turnstile 1 " + turnstile.getPort() +  " , " + turnstile.getLocalAddress());

        String socketIp = turnstile.getLocalAddress().toString();
        String socketName = "Turnstile-" + socketIp.substring((socketIp.length()-1) , socketIp.length());
        System.out.println(socketName);

        while (true) {

            InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(turnstile.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufreader = new BufferedReader(input);
            String message = bufreader.readLine();

            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                count++;
                printToTerminal.println(" Number of clients " + count);
            }
            if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("close")){
            turnstile.close();
            }
        }

    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: Well I have to use telnet to stimulate turnstiles with threads. So lets say I open 4 telnets/turnstiles and each turnstiles need threads, i dont know how use the threads. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Well that is easy to fix, you should go through the following resources: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ and http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html. For more specific answer, you should provide more specific question.

Comment: How do I use threads in order to simulate multiple telnets? I have looked at the resources you gave before, its kinda hard to get, i'm new at programming sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your example does what you need, right?  Then it's working for ONE thread.  You probably want to "wrap up" the code you already have into a class or two instead of writing static code in your main method, and make at least one class implement the Runnable interface.  Then you can call that code once for each "turnstile" thread you want to spin up.  Something like this

```
Runnable r = new MyRunnableClass("someArgLikeThreadID");
r.start();
```

You probably also want to implement a "TurnstileManager" class to manage startup and shutdown for all the threads that will ever run.

Since you used the word "assignment", my answer is deliberately not spelling everything out.  The absolute best way to learn is by "problem solving" and working your own way around or through difficulties you encounter along the way to crafting the application your heart desires.

Comment: Yeah it works with one thread. Thanks for the advice i'm gonna try it out.